# Bash redirector not redirecting output to file

Tags: bash

I have my script like this:

`git clone https://github.com/ITdairy/whatsapp-for-linux 2>&1 > log.txt`

But the `git` still show the output in the terminal, and `cat log.txt` shows nothing.

[image: Here is the image of the script]

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/ITdairy/whatsapp-for-linux > log.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

Swap the redirection. First you send stdout to a file the redirect stderr to stdout.

`grep > /tmp/log 2>&1; sleep 2; cat /tmp/log`

output this after 2 seconds:

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way and it worked for me:

```
git clone --progress https://github.com/ITdairy/whatsapp-for-linux &>log.txt
```

Source:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/989015/how-to-get-git-producing-output-to-a-file